# Safely move debian partition from windows

Tags: dual-boot, partition-table, move-partition

I have a laptop with Windows 10 and Debian 10 installed as dual boot. The problem is that I want to expand my Debian partition, which is 40GB, but from Windows Partition Manager I see that space in the disk as 'unallocated'.

If a reduce the C: Windows space, how can I then expand the Debian partition? Because it is not detected as a used partition, just unused space.

The Debian partition is at the end, so if I added like 20GB 'to the left' I'm not sure if that would move the 'main os partition' and then not being able to boot it.

Comment: Only use Windows tools to modify NTFS partitions. Use gparted for Linux partitions. You have to move left & expand right. If just move, UUID should not change, but you always have good backups of everything on a drive whenever making major changes.

Comment: But it's strange that your Debian partition is shown as unallocated space, that should not be. Boot from a Linux Live CD from USB and use `gparted`. Add screenshots to your question if unsure.

Answer (score 1):

## No not with MS-Windows

You can't: Windows partition manager can't resize (or even recognise) Linux partitions.

## How to do it

You can however use it to shrink it's own partition. Then boot from a live Distro (gparted is a good one for this job). From there re-size the Debian root.

---

You may also want to consider having a `/home` partition. Probably not on your first install, but the 2nd time. It will allow upgrades to new OS, without loosing the content of `/home`.

Comment: But can't I like update the grub menu or somehow tell it the new location? I don't mind reinstalling it (now) but I don't know how to make it so that in the future I can move space from Windows to Debian partition or vice versa in case that I need more space.

Comment: I don't see what grub has to do with it. I have edited answer to make it clearer.